# Access nested json value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I want to get the geometry/location lat and lng values from this Google Maps API call http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Marshal+Tito+12+Skopje&sensor=false

I tried few approaches but it doesn't get me the data I need, this is what I tried:

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(result[0].results.geometry);
console.log(result.results[0].geometry);
```

But I'm getting undefined values.

What do I need to modify in order to get the geometry/location (lat,lng) values?

Comment: Did you try `console.log(result)`?

Comment: should this work `console.log(results.results[0].geometry);`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to acces nested objects by name 
like: `results[0].geometry.location.lat`

as here http://jsfiddle.net/5pjha/

Answer (score 0):

to access object, you can use dot(.) to access the nested object, e.g.,

```
const user = {
  firstName: 'Alongkorn',
  lastName: 'Chetasumon',
  age: 25,
  address: {
    country: 'Thailand',
    location: {
      lat: 123,
      lng: 456
    }
  }
};

const lat = user.address.location.lat;
console.log(lat); // print 123
```

from http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Marshal+Tito+12+Skopje&sensor=false

to get `lat` and `lng` by `results[0].geometry.location.lat` and `results[0].geometry.location.lng`